# Delegate in C++11

Tags: c++, delegates, c++11

Does C++11 provide delegates?

If not, what is the best (most efficient) way to do something similar in C++?  Boost.Signals?  FastDelegate?  Something else?

Comment: Whats wrong with function pointers?

Comment: I can't use it with class method :/

Comment: yes you can http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html but there are probably better things to use e.g. C++ functions don't need to be methods, or you could turn the class into a functor

Answer (score 15):

You can get delegate-like semantics using `bind` to bind a member function to a class instance:

```
#include <functional>

struct C 
{
    void Foo(int) { }
};

void Bar(std::function<void(int)> func) 
{ 
    func(42); // calls obj.Foo(42)
}

int main() 
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;

    C obj;
    Bar(std::bind(&C::Foo, obj, _1));
}
```

In this example, `Bar()` takes anything that has a single `int` parameter and that returns `void`.

In `main()`, we bind a pointer to the member function `C::Foo` to the instance of `C` named `obj`.  This gives us an object that can be called with a single `int` parameter and which returns `void`.

We call `Bar()` with this object and `Bar()` makes the call `obj.Foo(42)`.

Comment: @jk:  Only sometimes.  Obviously in this case you could, but I don't have many classes in my application that have only one member function :-)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need c++0x. in `<functional>` you have `bind1st` `bind2nd` `mem_fun` and `mem_fun_ref`. You also have [Boost.Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/bind/bind.html) which generalizes all of the above functions (IIRC).

Going from memory ...

```
vector<Foo> foo = makeVector();
vector<Foo*> foop = makeVectorP();
vector<Bar> bar1,bar2,bar3,bar4;
transform( foo.begin(), foo.end(), back_inserter( bar1 ), mem_fun_ref(&Foo::getBar) );
transform( foop.begin(), foop.end(), back_inserter( bar2 ), mem_fun(&Foo::getBar) );
transform( foo.begin(), foo.end(), back_inserter( bar3 ), bind1st(&bar_from_foo) );
transform( foo.begin(), foo.end(), back_inserter( bar4 ), boost::bind(&bar_from_foo, _1) );
```

Comment: bind1st, bind2nd, mem_fun and mem_fun_ref are deprecated in C++11.

Answer (score 1):

Though `std::function` works nicely, I would like to point out this nice piece of delegate code, written [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14730/impossibly-fast-delegate-in-c11) (including example usage!). Following the references and answers there you can read all about how this `Delegate` class is constructed and why it may be faster than `std::function`.

Note also my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35912409/impossibly-fast-delegate-in-c11-on-msvc14?noredirect=1#comment59578925_35912409) for a problem I encountered with it on VS 2015.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to wait for C++0x. You can implement Delegates almost as well in the current C++03 standard.
You simply have to overload the operator (), so as you can call `MyObjectFunctor functor; functor();` and since the functor is an object, you can pass it as a delegate/object into functions;

the current version of the STL defines the header `<algorithm>` that provides functions ready to be used with Functors/Lambdas/Delegates.

simple example of a functor.

```
struct FunctorDelegate
{
    // as so to delegate as a function that takes an int input
    void operator()(int) 
    {
        // do what I want
    }
};

int main()
{
    //... do some stuffs with an std::vector<int> aRange; 
    FunctorDelegate functor;
    std::for_each(aRange.begin(), arange.end(), functor);
}
```

Comment: What delegates can do is the ability to store, for example, `int A::func1(int, int)` or `int B::func2(int, int)` in a variable (say `f`), so that it could be called like `int v = f(a, 12, 34);` or `int v2 = f(b, 42, 24);`. In your example, the functor could be called, but it cannot be treated as an abstraction of the function type `void(int)`.

Answer (score -1):

The C mechanism has always been function pointer & baton (except for qsort() and bsearch() which didn't take a baton).

So one would always pass the class object as the baton.

E.G.:

```
class tp {
    public:
        tp() { n = 0; }
        void m(int z) { printf("%d is %d\n", n++, z++); }
        int n;
};

void higher_func(int *opx, int cnt, void *handler(int itm, void *baton), void *baton)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
        handler(opx[itm], baton);
}

/* You would need to provide this stub -- potentially templateable */
void translate_baton(int itm, void *baton) { ((tp *)baton)->m(itm); }

/* used like so: */
int main()
{
    int array[7];

    //...
    tp cx;
    higher_func(array, 7, translate_baton, &cx);
}
```

Comment: This question isn't about C: the C mechanism is available in C++ but that doesn't make it the best option.

Comment: I do a lot of work with delegates in .NET and believe me this way would have saved me trouble over the way of delegates than rather the other way around.