# Impossibly fast Delegate in C++11 on MSVC++14

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, delegates, visual-studio-2015

### The Problem

This question relates to several questions about function pointers here (I will not list them), but most importantly it concerns the code posted [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14730/impossibly-fast-delegate-in-c11). The post claims the code should be standard compliant and it compiles on Apple Clang just fine.

**I have not managed to compile it** in VS2015, i.e. MSVC++14.

**What could be the source of this error and why not with Clang?**

---

### First Error

First error repeats multiple times:

```
...\Delegate.hpp(329): error C2514: 'Delegate<R(A...)>::is_member_pair<<unnamed-symbol>>':
class has no constructors
```

And the same for `is_member_pair_const`. It relates to the following part of the code:

```
  template <typename T>
  static typename ::std::enable_if<
    !(is_member_pair<T>{} ||
    is_const_member_pair<T>{}),
    R>::type
  functor_stub(void* const object_ptr, A&&... args)
  {
    return (*static_cast<T*>(object_ptr))(::std::forward<A>(args)...);
  }
```

---

### Second Error

Multiple errors appear, but the first is usually most important:

```
...\Delegate.hpp(340): error C2059: syntax error: '<end Parse>'
...\Delegate.hpp(349): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Delegate<R(A...)>' being compiled
```

Then follow a few syntax errors, unrecognizable template declaration/definition etc. The code in question:

```
  template <typename T>
  static typename ::std::enable_if<
    is_member_pair<T>{} ||
    is_const_member_pair<T>{},
    R
  >::type
  functor_stub(void* const object_ptr, A&&... args)
  {
    return (static_cast<T*>(object_ptr)->first->*
      static_cast<T*>(object_ptr)->second)(::std::forward<A>(args)...);
  }
```

---

**For Completeness: The entire Delegate.hpp:**

[Code Source](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14730/impossibly-fast-delegate-in-c11) and [Base Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11015/The-Impossibly-Fast-C-Delegates)

```
#pragma once
#ifndef DELEGATE_HPP
#define DELEGATE_HPP

#include <cassert>

#include <memory>

#include <new>

#include <type_traits>

#include <utility>

template <typename T> class Delegate;

template<class R, class ...A>
class Delegate<R (A...)>
{
  using stub_ptr_type = R (*)(void*, A&&...);

  Delegate(void* const o, stub_ptr_type const m) noexcept :
    object_ptr_(o),
    stub_ptr_(m)
  {
  }

public:
  Delegate() = default;

  Delegate(Delegate const&) = default;

  Delegate(Delegate&&) = default;

  Delegate(::std::nullptr_t const) noexcept : Delegate() { }

  template <class C, typename =
    typename ::std::enable_if< ::std::is_class<C>{}>::type>
  explicit Delegate(C const* const o) noexcept :
    object_ptr_(const_cast<C*>(o))
  {
  }

  template <class C, typename =
    typename ::std::enable_if< ::std::is_class<C>{}>::type>
  explicit Delegate(C const& o) noexcept :
    object_ptr_(const_cast<C*>(&o))
  {
  }

  template <class C>
  Delegate(C* const object_ptr, R (C::* const method_ptr)(A...))
  {
    *this = from(object_ptr, method_ptr);
  }

  template <class C>
  Delegate(C* const object_ptr, R (C::* const method_ptr)(A...) const)
  {
    *this = from(object_ptr, method_ptr);
  }

  template <class C>
  Delegate(C& object, R (C::* const method_ptr)(A...))
  {
    *this = from(object, method_ptr);
  }

  template <class C>
  Delegate(C const& object, R (C::* const method_ptr)(A...) const)
  {
    *this = from(object, method_ptr);
  }

  template <
    typename T,
    typename = typename ::std::enable_if<
      !::std::is_same<Delegate, typename ::std::decay<T>::type>{}
    >::type
  >
  Delegate(T&& f) :
    store_(operator new(sizeof(typename ::std::decay<T>::type)),
      functor_deleter<typename ::std::decay<T>::type>),
    store_size_(sizeof(typename ::std::decay<T>::type))
  {
    using functor_type = typename ::std::decay<T>::type;

    new (store_.get()) functor_type(::std::forward<T>(f));

    object_ptr_ = store_.get();

    stub_ptr_ = functor_stub<functor_type>;

    deleter_ = deleter_stub<functor_type>;
  }

  Delegate& operator=(Delegate const&) = default;

  Delegate& operator=(Delegate&&) = default;

  template <class C>
  Delegate& operator=(R (C::* const rhs)(A...))
  {
    return *this = from(static_cast<C*>(object_ptr_), rhs);
  }

  template <class C>
  Delegate& operator=(R (C::* const rhs)(A...) const)
  {
    return *this = from(static_cast<C const*>(object_ptr_), rhs);
  }

  template <
    typename T,
    typename = typename ::std::enable_if<
      !::std::is_same<Delegate, typename ::std::decay<T>::type>{}
    >::type
  >
  Delegate& operator=(T&& f)
  {
    using functor_type = typename ::std::decay<T>::type;

    if ((sizeof(functor_type) > store_size_) || !store_.unique())
    {
      store_.reset(operator new(sizeof(functor_type)),
        functor_deleter<functor_type>);

      store_size_ = sizeof(functor_type);
    }
    else
    {
      deleter_(store_.get());
    }

    new (store_.get()) functor_type(::std::forward<T>(f));

    object_ptr_ = store_.get();

    stub_ptr_ = functor_stub<functor_type>;

    deleter_ = deleter_stub<functor_type>;

    return *this;
  }

  template <R (* const function_ptr)(A...)>
  static Delegate from() noexcept
  {
    return { nullptr, function_stub<function_ptr> };
  }

  template <class C, R (C::* const method_ptr)(A...)>
  static Delegate from(C* const object_ptr) noexcept
  {
    return { object_ptr, method_stub<C, method_ptr> };
  }

  template <class C, R (C::* const method_ptr)(A...) const>
  static Delegate from(C const* const object_ptr) noexcept
  {
    return { const_cast<C*>(object_ptr), const_method_stub<C, method_ptr> };
  }

  template <class C, R (C::* const method_ptr)(A...)>
  static Delegate from(C& object) noexcept
  {
    return { &object, method_stub<C, method_ptr> };
  }

  template <class C, R (C::* const method_ptr)(A...) const>
  static Delegate from(C const& object) noexcept
  {
    return { const_cast<C*>(&object), const_method_stub<C, method_ptr> };
  }

  template <typename T>
  static Delegate from(T&& f)
  {
    return ::std::forward<T>(f);
  }

  static Delegate from(R (* const function_ptr)(A...))
  {
    return function_ptr;
  }

  template <class C>
  using member_pair =
    ::std::pair<C* const, R (C::* const)(A...)>;

  template <class C>
  using const_member_pair =
    ::std::pair<C const* const, R (C::* const)(A...) const>;

  template <class C>
  static Delegate from(C* const object_ptr,
    R (C::* const method_ptr)(A...))
  {
    return member_pair<C>(object_ptr, method_ptr);
  }

  template <class C>
  static Delegate from(C const* const object_ptr,
    R (C::* const method_ptr)(A...) const)
  {
    return const_member_pair<C>(object_ptr, method_ptr);
  }

  template <class C>
  static Delegate from(C& object, R (C::* const method_ptr)(A...))
  {
    return member_pair<C>(&object, method_ptr);
  }

  template <class C>
  static Delegate from(C const& object,
    R (C::* const method_ptr)(A...) const)
  {
    return const_member_pair<C>(&object, method_ptr);
  }

  void reset() { stub_ptr_ = nullptr; store_.reset(); }

  void reset_stub() noexcept { stub_ptr_ = nullptr; }

  void swap(Delegate& other) noexcept { ::std::swap(*this, other); }

  bool operator==(Delegate const& rhs) const noexcept
  {
    return (object_ptr_ == rhs.object_ptr_) && (stub_ptr_ == rhs.stub_ptr_);
  }

  bool operator!=(Delegate const& rhs) const noexcept
  {
    return !operator==(rhs);
  }

  bool operator<(Delegate const& rhs) const noexcept
  {
    return (object_ptr_ < rhs.object_ptr_) ||
      ((object_ptr_ == rhs.object_ptr_) && (stub_ptr_ < rhs.stub_ptr_));
  }

  bool operator==(::std::nullptr_t const) const noexcept
  {
    return !stub_ptr_;
  }

  bool operator!=(::std::nullptr_t const) const noexcept
  {
    return stub_ptr_;
  }

  explicit operator bool() const noexcept { return stub_ptr_; }

  R operator()(A... args) const
  {
//  assert(stub_ptr);
    return stub_ptr_(object_ptr_, ::std::forward<A>(args)...);
  }

private:
  friend struct ::std::hash<Delegate>;

  using deleter_type = void (*)(void*);

  void* object_ptr_;
  stub_ptr_type stub_ptr_{};

  deleter_type deleter_;

  ::std::shared_ptr<void> store_;
  ::std::size_t store_size_;

  template <class T>
  static void functor_deleter(void* const p)
  {
    static_cast<T*>(p)->~T();

    operator delete(p);
  }

  template <class T>
  static void deleter_stub(void* const p)
  {
    static_cast<T*>(p)->~T();
  }

  template <R (*function_ptr)(A...)>
  static R function_stub(void* const, A&&... args)
  {
    return function_ptr(::std::forward<A>(args)...);
  }

  template <class C, R (C::*method_ptr)(A...)>
  static R method_stub(void* const object_ptr, A&&... args)
  {
    return (static_cast<C*>(object_ptr)->*method_ptr)(
      ::std::forward<A>(args)...);
  }

  template <class C, R (C::*method_ptr)(A...) const>
  static R const_method_stub(void* const object_ptr, A&&... args)
  {
    return (static_cast<C const*>(object_ptr)->*method_ptr)(
      ::std::forward<A>(args)...);
  }

  template <typename>
  struct is_member_pair : std::false_type { };

  template <class C>
  struct is_member_pair< ::std::pair<C* const,
    R (C::* const)(A...)> > : std::true_type
  {
  };

  template <typename>
  struct is_const_member_pair : std::false_type { };

  template <class C>
  struct is_const_member_pair< ::std::pair<C const* const,
    R (C::* const)(A...) const> > : std::true_type
  {
  };

  template <typename T>
  static typename ::std::enable_if<
    !(is_member_pair<T>{} ||
    is_const_member_pair<T>{}),
    R
  >::type
  functor_stub(void* const object_ptr, A&&... args)
  {
    return (*static_cast<T*>(object_ptr))(::std::forward<A>(args)...);
  }

  template <typename T>
  static typename ::std::enable_if<
    is_member_pair<T>{} ||
    is_const_member_pair<T>{},
    R
  >::type
  functor_stub(void* const object_ptr, A&&... args)
  {
    return (static_cast<T*>(object_ptr)->first->*
      static_cast<T*>(object_ptr)->second)(::std::forward<A>(args)...);
  }
};

namespace std
{
  template <typename R, typename ...A>
  struct hash<::Delegate<R (A...)> >
  {
    size_t operator()(::Delegate<R (A...)> const& d) const noexcept
    {
      auto const seed(hash<void*>()(d.object_ptr_));

      return hash<typename ::Delegate<R (A...)>::stub_ptr_type>()(
        d.stub_ptr_) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
    }
  };
}

#endif // DELEGATE_HPP
```

Comment: [OT]: `using stub_ptr_type = R (*)(void*, A&&...);` seems suspicious. Do you really want rvalue references ? (Apply to most `A&&` in fact).

Comment: @Jarod42 Suspicious in what way? I think they are used in order to have it run proper fast. "Rvalue references allow a function to branch at compile time ", see http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_03.html
But I have not really grasped this implementation. It's very advanced and not written by me.

Comment: Try replacing `is_member_pair<T>{}` with `is_member_pair<T>::value` throughout (and same for `is_const_member_pair`)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that seems to have done the trick, thanks! If you post it as an answer with a short description I will check it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Igor commented, the following solves the problem: replace `is_member_pair<T>{}` with `is_member_pair<T>::value` everywhere and do the same for `is_const_member_pair`.

Comment: It works for me (Visual Studio 2017), but I don't know why... Where I can find some documentation about this so I can study it?